# VueJs Calling method in Child components

Tags: components, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a prop

```
<graph :active-metrics="$data.active_metrics"></graph>
```

In my child component I can access the value

```
export default {
      template: '<div>{{activeMetrics}}</div>',
      props: ['active-metrics'],
        methods: {
```

What I need to do is trigger a method in the child whenever there is a change. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props) to make the data from the parent flow down to the child.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
<graph v-bind:active-metrics="$data.active_metrics"></graph>

export default {
  template: '<div>{{activeMetrics}}</div>',
  props: ['active-metrics'],
  watch: {
    'active-metrics': function(){
      alert('active-metrics updated');
  }
}
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gqrh1ou1/2/) for a working JSFiddle.

Comment: I actually solved it by  this.$children[1].getMetrics(this.active_metrics); but your method is much nicer. Thanks.