# Vue.js: Communicate with components that are down the DOM

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm just trying out Vue.js and I'm struggling with the key concept of **passing information up and down the DOM** from one component to the other.

Consider this example in which a **container-toggle button should toggle all components** within the container, or say, set them all to "true" or "false".

[image: Example application screenshot]

```
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <strong>Welcome!</strong>
    Click the "true/false" buttons to toggle them. 
    Click the "Toggle all" button to toggle them all!
  </p>

  <app-toggle-container>
    <app-toggle></app-toggle>
    <app-toggle></app-toggle>
  </app-toggle-container>

  <app-toggle-container>
    <app-toggle></app-toggle>
    <app-toggle></app-toggle>
    <app-toggle></app-toggle>
  </app-toggle-container>
</div>
```

In this code pen, I've defined `app-toggle` and `app-toggle-container` as components: https://codepen.io/fiedl/pen/mmqLMN?editors=1010

But I can't find a good way to **pass the information down from the container to the separate toggles**.

Also, in a second step, when trying the other way round, for example, to have the "Toggle all" button just show "true" if all toggles are true, or to show "false" when all toggles are false, I can't find a way to **pass the information of the current state of the toggles up to the container**.

This doesn't seem like an uncommon problem. What is the proper way to do this in Vue.js? Or am I thinking about this it in the wrong way?

Quickly, I've found `$broadcast` and `$dispatch`. But as they are dropped in Vue.js 2, I'm most probably thinking about it in the wrong way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your pen http://codepen.io/nicooga/pen/wdPXvJ.

Turns out theres a `$children` property for Vue components that contains your children components [controllers]. You can iterate over them and do stuff with them.

```
this.$children.forEach(c => c.toggle());
```

See

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children
- [VueJs Calling method in Child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806014/vuejs-calling-method-in-child-components).

Comment: This works great, thank you very much! The other way round, `this.$parent.someMethod()` does also work!